# Error when specifying meta parameter of json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas

The below code works as expected

```
data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "name": 'record1',
            "values": [
                {
                    "key_1": "test_1",
                    "value": "1000"
                },
                {
                    "key_1": "test_2",
                    "value": "1001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["results","values"],meta=["results"])
display(df)
```

But I get the following error when I try the below - `"Key 'name' not found`

```
data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "name": 'record1',
            "values": [
                {
                    "key_1": "test_1",
                    "value": "1000"
                },
                {
                    "key_1": "test_2",
                    "value": "1001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["results","values"],meta=["results","name"])
display(df)
```

The only difference is the inclusion of the "name" attribute in my meta path. What is the correct way to specify the meta path in this case? I am looking for a 3 column result with key_1, value, and results.name.

**Update** - Was able to get this to work with my sample JSON (see response below) but it is not working with my production JSON.

```
{ 
    "createdAt": "2020-12-20T13:37:33.647Z",                        
    "completedAt": "2020-12-20T13:37:33.647Z",                            
    "header": { 
        "runId": "4c8f8516-cc55-4974-8856-9d2ea59d9aad", 
        "requestId": "2c8f8516-cc55-4974-8856-9d2ea59d9aae", 
        "metaData": {                                                
            "contentType": "pdf",
            "attachmentId": "3933",                      
        }
    }, 
    "body": {
        "documentMetadata": { 
            "documentSize": 505,                                    
            "pageCount": 23                                         
        },
        "results": [
            {                                                       
                "type": "table",           
                "tableName": "table_1",              
                "rows": [                                           
                    { 
                        "name:": "id_1",           
                        "values": [                                 
                            { 
                                "name": "field_1",          
                                "value": "1001"                       
                            },             
                            { 
                                "name": "field_2",          
                                "value": "1002"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    { 
                        "name:": "id_2", 
                        "values": [ 
                            { 
                                "name": "field_1",          
                                "value": "1001"                       
                            },             
                            { 
                                "name": "field_2",          
                                "value": "1002"
                            } 
                        ]
                    }  
                ] 
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

`df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["body","results","rows","values"],meta=[["body","results","rows","name"]])`

Returns an error - `Key 'name' not found.`

**Update 2** - There was an error in my production JSON. The first answer resolves my question. Sorry about that!

Comment: Please include the error in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the error by using below:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["results","values"],meta=[["results", "name"]])
```

as meta expects a path relative to the data that you are normalizing. The error is because it is trying to traverse the path data["name"] which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. That did work for my sample JSON but doesn't seem to work for my production JSON (which is a bit more nested). I wonder if it's actually an issue with my JSON?

Updating original question now.